# Converting UIImage to CIImage Returns nil

Tags: swift, uiimage, ciimage

I'm trying to convert the `UIImage` from an imageView into a `CIImage` for the purpose of filtering it. However, I cannot get the `CIImage` to have a value.

In the simplest form, here's what I am trying:

```
let ciInput = CIImage(image: imageView.image!)
```

but the ciInput always is nil.
I have also tried

```
let ciInput = CIImage(cgImage: imageView.image!.cgImage)
```

but also returns nil.

`(imageView.image` is not nil, but `imageView.image!.cgImage` and `imageView.image!.ciImage` are both nil)

I need to convert the `UIImage` from the `imageView` into a valid `CIImage`. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Here is the full function code

```
func makeWhiteTransparent(imageView: UIImageView) {

    let invertFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)

    let ciInput = CIImage(image: imageView.image!) //This is nil
    invertFilter?.setValue(ciInput, forKey: "inputImage")

    let ciOutput = invertFilter?.outputImage
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciOutput?.extent)!)

    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

When running this function, I get a fatal unwrapping nil error on the last line. Using the debugger, I discovered that the ciInput is nil, which it should not be.

EDIT 2:
The image on the imageView before calling makeWhiteTransparent is a QR code generated with this function:

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 12, y: 12)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: How was `imageView.image` first created? If you added a line of code `let uiImage = imageView.image` what happens? Finally, note that you are force-unwrapping `imageView.image`. It seems to me you aren't posting enough code.

Comment: How have you instantiated the `UIImage` in that `imageView`?

Comment: How exactly do you know that the CIImage is `nil`? Please show us, from start to finish, how to reproduce this issue, starting with the image, the image view, how the image gets into the image view, where your code runs, and how you come to the conclusion that `ciInput` is `nil`.

Comment: I added the whole function for more detail, and marked which variable is nil. The nil variable, ciInput, eventually causes an "unexpectedly found nil..." error

Comment: Hmm. There are minor changes I might suggest, but this code works for me as is. I'm wondering if there's something special about the image?

Comment: You are not showing the code which creates and sets the original `UIImage` to the `imageView`, before calling your `makeWhiteTransparent(imageView:)`. That may affect if you can get `CIImage` or not.

Comment: The original image is a QR code generated using a CIFilter named "CIQRCodeGenerator", that might have an effect on it?

Comment: Possibly, but I cannot say anything definite without seeing the code.

Comment: @OOPer I updated the question with the QR generation function

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was in my QR Code generation. The code returned a UIImage from a CIImage without properly utilizing CGContext to return the UIImage. Here is the corrected QR Code function that fixed the issue.

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 12, y: 12)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
            let context = CIContext()
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: As you know, `CIImage` is sort of a collection of image processing functions and it does not have a concrete bitmap buffer. `UIImage` created with such things may return `nil` for `cgImage` or `CIImage.init(image:)` may return `nil`. Anyway, good job. Your code is exactly the same as what I prepared.