# QR Code Detection from UIImage failed while converting UIImage to CIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, qr-code

I am trying to decode a QR code to get its contents. Following is the code for it :

```
func detectQRCode(_ recImage: UIImage?) -> [CIFeature]?
{
    if let img = recImage,
    let ciImage = CIImage.init(image: img)
    {
        var options: [String: Any]
        let context = CIContext()
        options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let qrDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: context, options: options)
        if ciImage.properties.keys.contains((kCGImagePropertyOrientation as String))
        {
            options = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: ciImage.properties[(kCGImagePropertyOrientation as String)] ?? 1]
        }
        else
        {
            options = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: 1]
        }
        let features = qrDetector?.features(in: ciImage, options: options)
        return features
    }
    return nil
}
```

if let statement fails at `let ciImage = CIImage.init(image: img)`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get `ciImage` from property of `UIImage` like -

```
if let ciImage = recImage?.ciImage
```

Updated Code should look like this -

```
func detectQRCode(_ recImage: UIImage?) -> [CIFeature]?
{
    if let ciImage = recImage?.ciImage
    {
        var options: [String: Any]
        let context = CIContext()
        options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let qrDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: context, options: options)
        if ciImage.properties.keys.contains((kCGImagePropertyOrientation as String))
        {
            options = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: ciImage.properties[(kCGImagePropertyOrientation as String)] ?? 1]
        }
        else
        {
            options = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: 1]
        }
        let features = qrDetector?.features(in: ciImage, options: options)
        return features
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Note from the doc which may still fail: "If the UIImage object was initialized using a CGImageRef, the value of the property is nil."

Comment: @Larme - Yes that's right. Please suggest for that situation.

Comment: I'd suggest `let ciImage = CIImage(image: img)` but apparently if fails too, and I don't know the reason. Maybe there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686151/converting-uiimage-to-ciimage-returns-nil

Comment: @Rizwan - Its working, thanks. Also, how to overcome other situation when initialized using CGImageRef as suggested by Larme.

Comment: @Nawaz - check the link shared by Larme.